# VPS server all domains showing This site can’t be reached error

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, centos8

Hello all hoping someone may be able to help.

I have a VPS server running apache with linux centos 8. I have a few domains running on PHP 8 and one wordpress and node API application. Everything was working fine until this morning I tried accessing my websites and all domains are getting the This site can't be reached message. I have tried on multiple browsers and devices.
I checked apache is running
when I run ping against my domain my VPS IP address is returned and see nothing in server or application logs (/var/log directory)

What can possibly cause this does anyone know or can anyone provide any guidance. My VPS is with hostinger and they wont help since its self managed hosting. Since the last time i used my application I did not make any configuration or server changes.

One of my sites is https://screenshottopdf.com

Comment: It would be very useful to have the actual name of one of your sites so we can run diagnostics ourselves. As it is I don't know whether to suggest DNS, firewall, or some routing error.

Comment: Sorry about that I just edited my post and put the site in there - thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really hate to suggest that a reboot might be useful - I've been in the Windows world for a long time - but it looks like Apache is not responding, and restarting it, or rebooting the entire VPS, might well bring you back up. I would also check whether your disk is full, as I've had one client who had a site fail multiple times because of an overfull system disk (found with `df -h`) and again because of inode exhaustion (found with `df -i`). Your DNS is working, and `traceroute` from here shows a long but not unmanageable path (21 hops, 50ms from Vancouver), so it would seem to be purely within your server.

Edit: Other things to check are whether there's a firewall active and if so, whether it's allowing inbound connections on ports 80 and 443. I'll note that I can connect to port 25, so there may be a mail server, and of course SSH is available. But at this point we're more in the realm of general troubleshooting, and for that, this venue is not particularly well suited.

Comment: I have rebooted the server twice already. Also as far as the disk space goes the hosting dashboard shows that its practically empty. I actually just set up the server about 2 weeks ago so I have not even used it too much Running df-h shows only 1% used. Thank you for checking though appreciate it.

Comment: Edited my answer with a few other things to check... but we seem to be in the realm of general troubleshooting now.

Comment: Running firewall-cmd --state shows its running. I just stopped it and now things came up. Thank you so much for taking the time. I don't even know how or why firewall was turned on.

Comment: You probably want to ensure that you have an inbound path through the firewall on ports 80 and 443, and then re-enable it. It can be very useful to decrease your attack surface. Glad I was able to help.

Comment: I have no idea how to set that up - i guess i need to google and figure this out. But in the meantime at list everything is up. Appreciate the help I have been trying to figure this out for the past 8 hours now